# C# convert string to datetime without time

Tags: c#, sql, datetime, format, converters

It seems like it is not possible what I want(at least according to some articles i have read). But just to double check it. I am reading a `DateTime` from my database. In the database it is written like "01.01.2011" but when I read it with SQL and store it in a `string` it says "01.01.2011 00:00:00". 
Then I thought OK, I will just cut the time from the `string`. But there is the trick, it seems like this is not possible. Even when I cut the "00:00:00" part from the `string` (and it just says "01.01.2011"), and covert it into a `DateTime`, the "00:00:00" is still being displayed. 
I am new to C#, but it seems like this part is a lot better solved in Java where you can define how you want your date and it is being displayed like that (without concatting time when you don't want it). 
So just to make it clear, is it really not possible to achieve what I want (and I have to take care of the right format in my presentation layer) or did I just not find the proper information?

Thanks

Comment: It is unclear to me what you are trying to achieve. Could you tell us what you are actually trying to do?Exchange last 'what i want' in your question with brief description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DateTime` in .Net is *always* a date and a time.  You can ignore the time portion if you like, but it is still there.   Internally, `DateTime` tracks the whole number of ticks since 1/1/0001.  (There are 10,000 ticks in a millisecond).  So it is not possible for a `DateTime` to *not* have a time component.

For date-only data, the common convention is to use a date with the time set to midnight (00:00:00).  You can get one of these from any `DateTime` by using its `.Date` property.

You'll want to be careful that once you ignore the time, that you *always* ignore the time.  Otherwise, you may get into problems when dealing with daylight saving time issues in places like Brazil - where the time transitions from 11:59:59 PM to 1:00:00 AM.  If you're not careful about how you handle your data, then date-only data stuffed in a `DateTime` at midnight could get misinterpreted as a local time that doesn't actually exist.

There is no built-in type for a true date without a time in the .NET Framework.  However, you can find it in the [`LocalDate`](http://nodatime.org/1.3.x/api/html/T_NodaTime_LocalDate.htm) structure of the [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org) library.  You might consider using that if you have a lot of date-based business logic.

Comment: thanks, that was acutally what i have found out too, but wanted to check it here(since i could not belive it). I have also read about Noda Time, but i thought before i try that i will check if it is really not possible with native C#. thanks again

Comment: NP.  Also, you were comparing to Java, but there are similar issues there.  `java.util.Date` is a date+time type, and so is `Calendar`.  Both Joda-Time and Java8 have a `LocalDate` type, similar to Noda Time's.

Answer (score 0):

`myDatTime.ToString("MMM dd, yyyy");` would do the trick

Comment: so i have to convert it from string to datetime (because from sql i get it as a string), then from datetime to string(when applying your function) and then again to datetime (because i need it as a datetime) ?

Comment: @user3466562 c# supports datetime type casting directly with database datetime type. So when you read/write to the data base you can just pass in the datatime object as parameter and it will happly accept it. If you want to display only the date without time then do the to string method

Comment: I saw that too, but the problem is when the datetime is null. So i thought i will read it as string and then process it. But this seems like a pain in the ass. According to this: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/4ff9b7c9-ef08-4fe3-a579-d8a0c7188796/remove-time-from-datetimeminvalue it is not possible to truncate the time from a datetime in c#. So I think i will have to check if the string date is empty and if not retrieve it as datetime

Comment: @user3466562 you should just use DateTime type in your DB instead of string...thats why it is there. You can check if the field is null by 'dataRow[Column] is DbNull' if not, cast it

Comment: in the DB it is of course a datetime type but without time (so it is actually just a date). But when i read it in c# from my DB it automatically concats "00:00:00" to my date (in no other language this is being done - java, delphi - there i just get my date as it is in my DB)

Comment: @user3466562 oh that..Then its normal. Because Date"Time" means its date + time, so the time portion is always there

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you .. this may help.

 **in c#:**
 `if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(yourDateTime)) 
          {
           yourDateTime.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
           }`

**in sql-server:**

```
select convert(varchar, yourDateTime ,102) as [yourDateTime]
```