# get date without time in c#

Tags: c#, date, time, get

i have a column on my table "AbsenteeismDate" (type=date) when i want to get rows contain a date it return 0 row.

this is my C# code :

```
DateTime ClassDate = DateTime.Parse(lblDate.Content.ToString());
var Abs = dbs.GETAbsenteeisms.Where(a => a.AbsenteeismDate == ClassDate ).ToList();
```

i checked it there is a problem :
"AbsenteeismDate" on database and "ClassDate" aren't equal.

eg.

```
AbsenteeismDate=1396-05-31
```

and

```
ClassDate=1396-05-31 12:00:00 AM
```

how can i get Date without Time with DateTime type because AbsenteeismDate's type is date on my database.

sorry i can't speak English very well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# convert string to datetime without time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26207910/c-sharp-convert-string-to-datetime-without-time)

Answer (score 7):

A `DateTime` always has a date and time portion, but if you want to get a `DateTime` of that date and the time value set to 12:00:00 midnight (00:00:00) use [`DateTime.Date`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var Abs = dbs.GETAbsenteeisms
   .Where(a => a.AbsenteeismDate == ClassDate.Date)
   .ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

You do just define date time but without the time:

```
string date = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Comment: This is the best way IMO, it allows maximum flexibility of the output string.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Date property:

```
DateTime ClassDate = DateTime.Parse(lblDate.Content.ToString());
var date = ClassDate.Date;
```

Otherwise  you will have to convert to string as follow

```
var date=ClassDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
string a = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
```

> **ToShortDateString()** converts the value of the current System.DateTime object to equivalent short date string representation. This means the Console output woulf be e.g.  *01.01.2017*

Answer (score 0):

**You can try like this byt setting the date format:**

```
DateTime ClassDate = DateTime.Parse(lblDate.Content.ToString(("yyyy-MM-dd"));
var Abs = dbs.GETAbsenteeisms.Where(a => a.AbsenteeismDate == ClassDate ).ToList();
```